# Unexpected NA from user-interactive code

Tags: r

I am trying to learn R programming and I need some help.  I am trying to get a user input and check if the number is an even or odd number.

```
user_input = suppressWarnings(as.integer(readline(prompt="Enter a number: ")))
if ((userinput %% 2) == 0)
  {
  print(paste(user_input,"is Event"))
}
```

But I'm getting an error message:

> Error Message:
>       [1] "NA is Event"

1. Why didn't it prompt the user to enter a number?
2. What does "NA is event" mean?

Comment: 1.) You have a typo on your second line; change `userinput` to `user_input` (or just make them consistent) 
2.) When I run the first line interactively it does prompt for a number - however if you run the whole thing interactively at once it won't wait for you and will assign NA to user_input. You need to read more about how the `readline` function is supposed to be used. Many things that run well from the command prompt don't run well (without modification) when you run them interactively.
3.) The "is Event" part is what YOU wrote.

Comment: @HFBrowning, you should propose this as the answer. BTW you just beat me to it :)

Comment: I am just learning :). Thank you for your comments :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from `?readline`:

> readline reads a line from the terminal (in interactive use).

so what happens when you run your code:

```
user_input = suppressWarnings(as.integer(readline(prompt="Enter a number: ")))
```

is that `readline` immediately prints the prompt, but then reads the next line of your script

```
 if ((user_input %% 2) == 0)
```

as if it's the users' input. This means the `if` doesn't get evaluated, and the next statement

```
print(paste(user_input,"is Event"))
```

gets executed right away. As `user_input` is `NA` what is printed is `NA is Event`.

you can see that this is what happens if you change your script to

```
user_input = suppressWarnings(as.integer(readline(prompt="Enter a number: ")))
2
if ((user_input %% 2) == 0)
{
  paste(user_input,"is Event")
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear and detailed explanations. You are awesome :)